# Android - Grey tint on ListView on click

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView with data from Json. The ListView display news from my website and I want to take grey tint (Opacity Grey) on read items.

So, after that user click on item I want to display the grey tint and I want to save in cache read items to redisplay the tint when the app is closed.

This in the item XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp">


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@layout/rectangle"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/imagearticleaccueil"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/nom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/client"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:background="#f7f7f7"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And after data loaded, this is how I add data in ListView:

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), donnees,
                R.layout.list_article, new String[]{"picture", "nom", "client"}, new int[]{R.id.imagearticleaccueil, R.id.nom, R.id.client});
        adapter.setViewBinder(new MyViewBinder());
mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** I added a Web API thanks to *Shaikh Ahmed*. I can now define if news are read or not. But I want to know how I can add a grey tint or grey opacity on the item if news is read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mark News As READ**,
You need to create a web API to mark the news as read for achieving this you need to setup the trigger on news so when user click on the news its should called the web API with the “user_id" and “news_id" which set the flag (that a particular user read a particular news) on server...

For Differentiating between “READ" and “UNREAD” news after that as you want to show a grey tint on read news you should have to add a parameter like "is_news_read" in the web API (from which you are getting all the news)....

Adapter for grey tint:

## Custom Adapter for Grey tint

```
public class ReadUnReadAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{



    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<NewsBean> mList;



public ReadUnReadAdapter (Context context,ArrayList<NewsBean> list)
{
    mContext = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext); 
    this.mList=list;

}
public class ViewHolder {
    TextView txt_top,txt_large;
    ImageView img_view;

}

public int getCount() {
    //return array_str_logo.length;
    return mList.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mList.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {

        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.name_of_your_xml_file, null);

            // Locate the TextViews in name_of_your_xml_file.xml

            holder.txt_top = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nom);
            holder.txt_large=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.client);
            holder.img_view=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagearticleaccueil);

            // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        /* This condition works like a magic by changing the value of alpha ....!  */
        if(mList.getIsNewsReaded())
        {
              convertView.setAlpha(0.7);
        }
        else
        {
              convertView.setAlpha(1.0);
        }
        holder.txt_top.setText(mList.getmHeading());
        holder.txt_large.setText(mList.getmText());
        holder.img_view.setImageUri(mList.getmImagePath());    
        return convertView;
    }


}// End of ReadUnReadAdapter
```

Comment: Ok for the API. But How to add the grey tint if news "is_news_read" ?

Comment: For **Grey tint**, you need to define a custom adapter in which you can set alpha to 0.7 on layout if the news is readed and set alpha to 1 on the  layout if the news is unreaded....!
And please mark the answer as correct....

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm going to mark the answer as correct when I have found a solution. I just want to know how do to the custom SimpleAdaptater with the Alpha parameters ?

Comment: I have updated the answer...Please check the custom adapter....This will mark the news as read and unread